# XCode .dylib file missing. Solution not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am getting the following error in my iPhone application:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
```

I found another stack overflow question which had a solution. So, I performed the following, as per that solution:

```
cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols

sudo ln -s ../../4.3.3\ \(8J2\)/Symbols/Developer/ Developer
```

And, the terminal returns:

```
ln: Developer: File exists
```

So the file exists? Or doesn't? Why am I getting this error in my iPhone application?

Comment: Sounds like a messed installation of Xcode and/or SDK -> reinstall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running your app on a device, simply try uninstalling your app from your device, then turning off your device, then back on again. It just worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the app and/or reset simulator.